# Are xdt transforms not supported in nuget packages installed in a netstandard 2.0 project?

Tags: nuget, .net-standard-2.0, xdt-transform

I have a nuget package that has .xdt transforms for a app.config file. The xdt files are included in the netstandard 2.0 project that builds the nuget package. Their build action is set to content/do not copy. When I install the package in a .net framework project, the xdt transforms work corectly, but when I install the package in a netstandard 2.0 project, the xdt files do not transform the config file, but instead are added to the project with a build action of C# Compiler. Does nuget not support xdt transforms on netstandard projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, xdt transforms aren't supported in `PackageReference` environment. This includes both sdk-based projects as well as classic .net framework projects using `PackageReference` instead of `packages.config`. You can follow [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5954) for more details. There is also a [sample package](https://github.com/NuGet/Samples/tree/master/XDTransformExample) that shows how to use build-time logic to apply transforms instead to work in all environments.

Also note that .NET Standard and .NET Core projects don't have an `app.config` file that a transform could apply to. This is only relevant for .NET Framework / classic Web Applications. (with maybe an exception for IIS settings for ASP.NET Core apps but they don't affect the app itself, only IIS hosting environment).